# Can't style theorem with ntheorem and mathdesign

Tags: ntheorem, mathdesign

Code below gives me no styling for theorem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{russ}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[OMLmathrm,OMLmathbf]{isomath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}


\newtheorem{lem}{Лема}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
За умов (5) для довільного $s \in (0,1)$ рівняння
\begin{equation}\label{6}
  sf(k)=\mu
\end{equation}
має єдиний розв'язок $k_{s}>0.\\$
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are no Cyrillic fonts with the `bitstream-charter` option to `mathdesign`, so the default ones are substituted and boldface or italics are lost during the substitution process.

Answer (score 2):

The `bitstream-charter` option to `mathdesign` doesn't provide Cyrillic fonts.

You get some warnings

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/mdbch/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 3.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/mdbch/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 15.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/mdbch/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/mdbch/m/n' instead on input line 17.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/mdbch/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/mdbch/m/n' instead on input line 18.
```

which mean just what I said: `T2A` is the encoding for Cyrillic and the `mdbch` font family (Bitstream Charter) has no font for it.

If you remove the loading of `mathdesign`, you get

[image]

I believe that *no* font coming with `mathdesign` has Cyrillic fonts.